# Implementing pre-made rotating banner into website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement the rotating jQuery banner found here:
http://visitmix.com/labs/glimmer/samples/sequence.html

onto my site. All of the code is laid out, and you'd think it would be idiot proof, but I don't have a firm grasp on how to connect languages to one another.

I'm pretty good now with PHP, CSS and HTML but javaSCRIPT and me just don't seem to click.

I copied the HTML over into my file at the appropriate location, copied the CSS, and copied the function into my js/scripts.js file.

This is what my scripts.js file looks like:

```
var site = function() {
    this.navLi = $('#nav li').children('ul').hide().end();
    this.init();
};

site.prototype = {

    init : function() {
        this.setMenu();
    },

    // Enables the slidedown menu, and adds support for IE6

    setMenu : function() {

    $.each(this.navLi, function() {
        if ( $(this).children('ul')[0] ) {
            $(this)
                .append('<span />')
                .children('span')
                    .addClass('hasChildren')
        }
    });

        this.navLi.hover(function() {
            // mouseover
            $(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow', 'easeOutBounce');
        }, function() {
            // mouseout
            $(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).hide();       
        });

    }

}


new site();

jQuery(function($) {
var timer;
function button1_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image1").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image1").css("opacity","0");
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button1").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button2_click"),"3000");
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function button2_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image2").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image2").css("opacity","0");
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button2").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button3_click"),"3000");
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function button3_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image3").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image3").css("opacity","0");
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button3").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button1_click"),"3000");
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function OnLoad(event)
{
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button2_click"),"3000");
}

$('#button1').bind('click', button1_click);

$('#button2').bind('click', button2_click);

$('#button3').bind('click', button3_click);

OnLoad();

});
```

I thought I had connected my scripts.js file to my HTML file by writing

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

But when the page is loaded, the buttons don't seem to rotate between the three images.

Can somebody spot my error(s), or tell me how to go about doing this?

EDIT: here is my CSS code for the portion that relates to the banner:

```
/* ROTATING BANNER CSS */

.slideshow {
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin-left: 12.5%;
margin-right: 12.5%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 8px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1000px;
height: 250px;
}
.slideshow a img {
border:none;
}
.slideshow li.slide {
list-style-type:none;
}
.slideshow .slides {
height:260px;
margin:0;
}
.slideshow .slides li.slide {
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0;
}
.slideshow .buttons {
display:none;
}
.slideshow .buttons {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
left:0px;
bottom:20px;
margin:0;
}
.slideshow .buttons li {
float:left;
display:inline;
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:0;
padding-left:11px;
line-height:30px;
background-image:url('buttonBg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.slideshow .buttons li a {
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
width:30px;
height:30px;
color:#fff;
outline:0;
}
.slideshow ul.buttons li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#0a0a0a;
}
.slideshow ul.buttons li.active a:hover,
.slideshow ul.buttons li.active a {
color:#666666;
}
```

Here is my HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>filler.com</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-image: url('images/bg.jpg')">
    <br />
    <div class="slideshow">
    <ul class="buttons">
    <li class="active" id="button1"><a href="#" title="warframebuilds">1</a></li>
    <li id="button2"><a href="#" title="create build">2</a></li>
    <li id="button3"><a href="#" title="forums">3</a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="slides">
    <li style="visibility:visible" class="slide" id="image1">
    <a href="http://www.filler.com/"><img alt="warframebuilds" src="images/bannerimg1.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="slide" id="image2">
    <a href="http://www.filler.com/create.php"><img alt="create build" src="images/bannerimg2.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="slide" id="image3">
    <a href="http://www.filler.com/forums"><img alt="forums" src="images/bannerimg3.png" /></a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Right click > View Source. Find that js/script.js line and click it, if it opens the js you should be fine, but my guess is that relative link isn't quite right.

Comment: it's `javaScript` and has nothing to do with `Java`

Comment: @RickCalder I clicked the link and it worked. Is my javaSCRIPT file formatted properly? I don't know the syntax well so I'm essentially just copying and pasting.

Comment: Getting familiar with [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) will help a lot with debugging JavaScript and learning as you go.

Comment: the use of `setTimeout(eval("button2_click"),"3000");` is an ugly one. just do instead `setTimeout(button2_click, 3000);`

Comment: Can you give your CSS, just want to confirm. Not sure if its a problem at my end, but CSS code seems to be an issue on the original link you provided.

Comment: I tried to do a fiddle, can you make similar for your images?
http://jsfiddle.net/TenzH/

Comment: Sure -- I added it here. It seems to work on fiddle, but not my site.

http://jsfiddle.net/SteelyDan/BykbZ/

Comment: [14:56:47.348] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ file:///C:/warframebuilds/js/scripts.js:38 ----- This is my current error when loading the page (related to js)

Comment: it looks like you are running your page locally and it can't load jQuery from the CDN

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem ^^ Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to swap two lines:

```
jQuery(function($) {  // short for jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 

    new site();

    var timer;
    // ...
```

In your code, the `new site()` was outside of the ready event. So in case you had your code at the beginning of your HTML, these elements were not (yet) ready and thus your code didn't work.

Note on using `setTimeout`: your example source did some ugly things, with unneeded `eval` and implicit string to number conversion. Just do

```
timer = setTimeout(button2_click, 3000);
```

Comment: I swapped it as you said, and checked my web dev error log-- I'm getting the error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined -- On line 38, which is the line of my scripts.js file corresponding to:**jQuery(function($) {**

Comment: have you opened your html file by `file://` protocol (just double clicked)? - then prepend `http:` to your url `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com...`

Comment: wow, that did it. Thanks so much man! I dont know why I didn't have that in there.

Cheers!

Comment: well on the net this is done to have automatically either `http` or `https`, however when you don't use a webserver, you're using `file` protocol, and there is not a harddisk `ajax.googleapis.com:` attached to your computer ;)

Comment: Ahhh. Makes sense! That's my jS ignorance shining through. Thanks so much. Site looks beautiful now thanks to you guys

Comment: pro tip: on jsFiddle.net click once on TidyUp and look how beautiful javaScript can be ;)